# PHP dynamical duplicate Mysqli results set

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, mysqli

I am attempting to populate 0 to many drop downs with the same results from a database table depending on a previous selection. it is working fine when 0 and 1 are selected but not when i am attempting to insert the result set into subsequent select elements. i am assuming it is a problem with the `$row` array position.

```
$homePlayers = "SELECT first_name, last_name, player_id FROM players WHERE team_name LIKE '$homeTeam%'";
$homePlayersQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $homePlayers);

if (!$homePlayersQuery) {
            echo 'err';
    } else {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $homeTeamScore; $i++) {
            echo "<select name='select-home-scorer-$i'>";

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($homePlayersQuery)) {
                echo current($row);
                echo "<option value='" . $row['player_id'] . "'>" . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "<option value='og'>Own Goal</option></select><br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the issue that you are running into. Error stack if present.

Comment: When you have got the last row using mysqli_fetch_array(), it will return no more rows, Use mysqli_data_seek() to start again.

Comment: ok @crafter so do i still use fetch array to get the records and data seek to reset the counter or is data seek used to get results also.

Comment: @Lonergan6275, data_seek to position 0 will rewind the pointer to the start of the results, so that you can run fetch all over again.

Comment: @crafter that worked if you want to add it in answer.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you experience is that mysqli_fetch_array() reads data of the result set once. When you have read the last record, subsequent calls to mysqli_fetch_array() will return false.

You have 2 choices.
Firstly, you can read the records into an array and repeatedly parse the array.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($homePlayersQuery)) {
    $resultsArray[] = $row;
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $homeTeamScore; $i++) {
   foreach($resultsArray as $resultItem) {
         do_something_here();
   }
}
```

}

As a second option, you could rewind the pointer to the mysql result set so that you can start reading the results again.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $homeTeamScore; $i++) {

   // Rewind the pointer to the start of the results
   mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($homePlayersQuery)) {
       $resultsArray[] = $row;
   }
}
```